# How to use Translate pipe of Ionic2?

Tags: ionic2

I would like to know how to user translate pipe built in Ionic2:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/translation/Translate/

What to import, form where, where is the .json file that include the translated words, etc...

The documentation is not clear at all, so I was not able to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Like this in the template (it does not work without the pipe argument for me):

```
{{ 'Hello world!' | translate:'' }}
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <ion-header>
      <ion-navbar>
        <button menuToggle>
          <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon> 
        </button>
        <ion-title>My page</ion-title>
      </ion-navbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content > 
        <h1>{{ 'Hello world!' | translate:'' }}</h1>
    </ion-content >
  `,
  directives: [],
  providers: [],
  pipes: [TranslatePipe]
})
export class MyPage {
    constructor(private translate:Translate) {
        this.translate.translations('fr', {
            'Hello world!': 'Salut les gens!'
        });
        this.translate.translations('de', {
            'Hello world!': 'Hallo zusammen!'
        });

        this.translate.setLanguage('fr');
  }
}
```

Of course, I should have setup globally the Translate service in the app.ts.

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

try to follow [this](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate) docs.

Btw you need to add in your app.module:

```
import { TranslateStaticLoader, TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from 'ng2-translate';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
    return new TranslateStaticLoader(http, './assets/i18n', '.json');
}
```

And in the imports section (after IonicModule.forRoot(...)):

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
  provide: TranslateLoader,
  useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
  deps: [Http] 
})
```

Now in your app.component add in your initialize function:

```
this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
this.translate.use('en');
```

Now you need to make an es.json or en.json file under assets/i18n/*.json for translations and in your html you can use:

```
{{ 'notifications' | translate }}
```

Hope this will help you.